# Connecting to Postgres Heroku DB through Intellij IDEA

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, intellij-idea

I've been trying to connect to my postgres DB all day.  I can do it through pgAdmin, but I can't connect through mySQLWorkbench to migrate it and also can't connect through Intellij IDEA.  We'll start w/Intellij though...

So, when I try to connect through IntelliJ, I get this...

```
Connection to Sinthetics failed
java.sql.SQLException: SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I take this to mean that I need a certificate, since I'm using SSL (because it's a postgres/heroku).  So, I run my handy InstallCert like so...

```
java InstallCert ec2-54-243-235-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432
```

And get this back:

```
Loading KeyStore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts...
Opening connection to ec2-54-243-235-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432...
Starting SSL handshake...

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:87)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    ... 4 more
Could not obtain server certificate chain
```

So why can't I get a cert for this, but it connects with no problem with pgAdmin!?  Does anybody have a clue at all?

Answer (score 35):

To add new connection to your PostreSQL on Heroku in Intellij Idea you need to:

1. Database Tool Window / New / Data Source / PostreSQL
2. Put Host, Port, Database, User, Password that you find on https://postgres.heroku.com/databases
3. Go to Advanced tab and put:

   - ssl: true
   - sslmode: verify-ca
   - sslfactory: org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
4. Profit.

Comment: That did not work for me, I am getting an error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
[2017-01-20 19:52:20]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[2017-01-20 19:52:20]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[2017-01-20 19:52:20]  at ...

Answer (score 3):

Create DB with Host, Port, Database, User, Password from data.heroku.com

Go to Advanced tab and put :

- ssl: **true**
- sslfactory: **org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory**

If you get error like this:

> Connection to xxx.amazonaws.com failed. [08006] The hostname
>   xxx.amazonaws.com could not be verified by hostnameverifier
>   PgjdbcHostnameVerifier

Just put this value to advanced tab too:

- sslmode: **verify-ca**

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue, downgrading to a minor version of `Postgre Driver` worked for me.

PostgreDriverSettings:

[image: PostgreDriverSettings]

Comment: Went from 42.2.5 to 42.2: 
DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 11.4); Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=exact; Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.2.2, JDBC4.2); Ping: 39 ms

Answer (score 1):

To connect I simply did this:

1. Go to your app on Heroku in Settings
2. Find the environment variable `DATABASE_URL`
3. Copy it and paste somewhere on you computer

The value of `DATABASE_URL` is something like this:

```
postgres://this-is-theuser:this-is-a-very-long-long-long-password@ec2-34-756-294-13.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/this-is-the-database
```

**DO NOT COPY AND PASTE THIS VALUE DIRECTLY IN THE `Url:` FIELD IN PHPSTORM**

Instead, put each value manually in the form letting PHPStorm itself build the URL and try to connect. It should work.